# How to GROUP BY using Iteration?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to GROUP the JSON by BOARD and SUM the likes_count, but not sure how to approach this, since I can only access the Transaction class by looping through Root first?

```
    public class Transaction
{
    public string Post { get; set; }
    public int board {get; set; }
    public int Sent_from { get; set; }
    public int likes_count { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int Sent_to { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

}

static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
{


    var json = "";      
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        json = wc.DownloadString("xxxxxxx");
    }
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);

    foreach (var item in obj)
    {

        foreach (var child in item.Transactions)
        {
            
            // access sent_from, likes_count and post.

        }

    }
}
```

I would've normally used:

```
obj.GroupBy(t => t.post);
```

Here is a JSON Sample:

```
Sent_to: X,
total_received_likes: X,
Transactions: [
{
Post: "50776785",
board: "600",
Sent_from: 359716,
likes_count: 4,
},
{
Post: "5085129785",
board: "500",
Sent_from: 359716,
likes_count: 6,
},
{

Post: "506542785",
board: "500",
Sent_from: 359716,
likes_count: 9,
},
```

The expected output in this case:

> 15 likes in board 500
>
> 4 likes in board 600.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Grouping the `Root`s by the sum of `likes_count` is understandable but how would you like to group by the `Post` if the `Post` can be different for each item of `Transactions`? Can you provide sample data and the expected output?

Comment: can you share the json and the expected result of the output json after grouping.

Comment: Can you try this var query = obj.Transactons.GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, Sum(x.Column2 )});

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I meant "board" and not post, I apologize. Edited and added sample JSON and expected OUTPUT as well.

Comment: @Sajid Added. Thanks

Comment: @CSharpdocsz What is the expected output if there are multiple `Root` objects? Do you only care about the `board` and sum of `likes-count`?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes that's all I care about and the JSON returned won't have more than one "Sent to" and "Total received likes" either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group the Transactions by `board` regardless of which `Root` they belong to and then calculate the sum of `likes_count` for each group, you may create a list using something like this:

```
var list = obj.SelectMany(r => r.Transactions)
              .GroupBy(t => t.board)
              .Select(g => new { Board = g.Key, TotalLikes = g.Sum(t => t.likes_count) })
              .ToList();
```

..which you can then use like this:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.TotalLikes} like(s) in board {item.Board}.");
}
```

You can also do the same thing for each `Root` separately if you like:

```
foreach (var root in obj)
{
    var list = root.Transactions
                   .GroupBy(t => t.board)
                   .Select(g => new { Board = g.Key, TotalLikes = g.Sum(t => t.likes_count) })
                   .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks :) 
As a side question, any good LINQ tutorials, or courses you would suggest?

Comment: @CSharpdocsz Everything is explained well in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). You can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) and follow the articles one by one. There are some simplified tutorials as well, like [this one](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-tutorials) which provides basic examples of how to use each method.